# tsql source control help please

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

According to the following section of BOL:

[How to: Use Source Control with SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173550.aspx)

If you have a source control client installed you should be able to choose it in the plug-in selection. I have both source control clients for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 (tfs2005) installed and there's no plug-in to choose in the list for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FAEB7636-644E-451A-90D4-7947217DA0E7&displaylang=en)

Comment: Do you know if this would affect the server in anyway with existing solutions and other developers who access it? In other words, could I install it without affecting other developer's access to the same solution? Will they be forced to install it?